# Indy 10 for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy10

Can Indy 10 be used with Delphi 7?

I am trying to find it, or purchase it. But, I cannot find any information on it.

I found where to download it, though:

http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/

Their website, http://www.atozed.com, does not give much information, either.

Answer (score 8):

Indy 10 supports Delphi/C++Builder 5 and higher. So yes, Delphi 7 is supported.

The official Indy website is http://www.indyproject.org.

Comment: This is an old post but felt it was relevant since it's the first result when searching "Delphi 7 Indy 10". In the github zip there are group projects based on the Delphi version. Delphi 7 (150) would be Indy150.groupproj, however this version should use .bpg. I attempted to build each of the projects in the Indy150 group project, then ran Fulld_7.bat. I then installed the design time controls in the outputted D7 folder. They appeared on the palette after installing but didn't work after closing. Is there somewhere with good directions on how to install with D7?

Comment: @four "*I attempted to build each of the projects in the Indy150 group project, then ran Fulld_7.bat*" - that is redundant, since the `.bat` builds the projects, so you don't need to build them yourself before running the `.bat`. "*They ... didn't work after closing*" - meaning what, exactly? Please be more specific. "*Is there somewhere with good directions on how to install with D7?*" - not specifically, no. Does [Updating Indy](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy) help?

Comment: "_meaning what, exactly?_" The IDE does not load the design time controls, stating that it cannot find the files. The path to the bpls is in my library path, and I verified that the files exist.  This is [after adding the design time components.](https://imgur.com/KH7GnNp).  [After closing/opening Delphi.](https://imgur.com/XV56fGz). [Files](https://imgur.com/oJtRisD)

Comment: @fourwhey Windows doesn't report *which* module can't be found, so the error is more likely complaining about the *other* BPL files that are involved, namely `IndySystem70.bpl`, `IndyCore70.bpl`, and `IndyProtocols70.bpl`, which the design-time BPLs are linked to. They are not shown in your screenshots. You can verify if this is the case by using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which files the IDE is actually looking for.

Comment: @fourwhey BTW, I just realized that you mentioned the `Indy150.groupproj` file earlier. That file is meant for Delphi XE, not for Delphi 7. There is an `Indy70.bpg` file for Delphi 7.

Comment: @RemyLeneau I see my mistake here. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Compiler_Versions Delphi vs Package version. I was looking at the wrong column. No wonder the group project didn't make sense. FullD7.bat should be correct though, right? There are no bpg files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254663/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-fourwhey).

Answer (score 0):

Installing Indy 10 in Delphi 7.

$(Delphi) is the path to your local Delphi 7 installation.

Download the github project zip for Indy 10.
https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy

Extract the zip to `C:\Repos\Indy10`

Open command prompt as Administrator, then type...
`C:`
`CD \Repos\Indy10\Lib`
`Fulld_7.bat`

After Fulld_7.bat build is completed with no errors, copy the contents of the outputted D7 folder from
`C:\Repos\Indy10\D7` to `$(Delphi)\Projects\Bpl`

Open Delphi 7.

Add library paths to Delphi 7.

Click `Tools` -> `Environment Options` -> `Library` tab.
Click ellipses button next to `Library path`.

Add `C:\Repos\Indy10\Lib\Core`
Add `C:\Repos\Indy10\Lib\System`
Add `C:\Repos\Indy10\Lib\Protocols`

Add component packages to Delphi 7
From D7 top menu Click `Component` -> `Install Packages` -> `Add`

Browse to `$(Delphi)\Projects\Bpl`
Add `dclIndyCore70.bpl`
Add `dclIndyProtocols70.bpl`

You should now have the Indy controls on the control palette.